# Google Sheets get row number of visible row

Tags: google-sheets

I want to get the row number of the first visible row on one of my sheets. So for example if rows 1 - 499 were hidden then I want to write a formula that returns the numerical value 500.

I know this will probably require the usage of the `ROW` function but I'm not sure how to write the required condition.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's assume your data is in column A
2. Create a new column B and write =row() into every cell of that column, so it will contain the row number
3. Use the following formula to calculate what you need:

   ```
   =subtotal(105,B:B)
   ```

It works like these: subtotal(105,range) shows you the minimum value of the range that is not hidden.